# Test case failed but shown as passed in intellij

Tags: exception

One of my test case is failed where I should get element not found exception but there is no such exception thrown and all my test cases are shown as passed .Using intellij community version,can anybody help me out of this???
Thanks in advance....

I have checked POM and testNG xml but all seems to be proper.

Comment: is this Java code you are talking about? if so, have you tried using the @Test annotation:
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentsException.class) or something like that?

Comment: It is working fine now,thanks Tom.

Comment: glad to help. please accept my answer below.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try using the @Test annotation:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentsException.class)
```